# Sort with a button for a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a button in my spreadsheet which sorts based on 3 criteria.
I tried about 20 different ways of writing the syntax, but none of those worked.
I'd be glad if someone could tell me what is wrong.

```
function sort1() {
   sort({C3:K12;9;FALSE;3;TRUE;8;FALSE})
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sort1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,3,10,9);
  rg.sort([{column:11,ascending:false},{column:5,ascending:true},{column:10,ascending:false}]);//The sort options is an array of objects but the array can be left for just one.
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Comment: ty very much for your answer at least it's valid syntax now, but the tables somehow aren't sorted like it should :/

Comment: Share a sample spreadsheet and  I'll take a look at it and see if we can resolve the problem.

Comment: ty for your time :)
here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SMVD9Z9rGQS4BYQOLyODfDX3cTXRhbApN1uLoc3RzNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: did u find a solution? @Cooper

Comment: How should they be sorted?

Comment: The column in the sort ranges are the actual column number in the sheet not in the table.

Comment: So I'm guessing that you really want to sort on column11 descending, 5 ascending, and 10 descending.  Let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally works, I'm super glad.

Answer (score 6):

If strict adherence to your predefined sorting criteria is not important, and you are happy to let users adjust the sort by themselves, you can achieve this result quite simply by selecting the region of data of interest, and then creating a ["filter"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on it.

[image: filter icon in Google Sheets tool bar]

A Google Sheets "filter" is really a rich sorting *and* filtering mechanism. Implemented this way, the end user can achieve the exact sort you mentioned by selecting the 3rd sort criterion (column 8 in your example), the 2nd (column 3), and then the 1st (column 9).

Example of a filter applied to a region of a sheet:

[image: Google Sheet data region with filter applied, showing several columns having filter controls]

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a Sheets function from an Apps Script like that. If you are writing the script yourself, you will need to get a range object and sort that. You may want to start by recording a macro, which will write the script for you (Tools > Macros). Then you can look at the script and see what it is doing. Once the script is working the way you want, here's a good post on running a script from a button: https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/

Answer (score 0):

Since you plan on doing 3 types of sorting, you could use **three buttons**, each for the wanted type of sort. Then you could attach to each one the type of sorting, like presented below.

The global variables `sheet` and `range`.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 11, 10);
```

The function `sort1` sorts your data by **points, descending**:

```
function sort1() {
 range.sort([{column:11,ascending:false}]);
}
```

The function `sort2` sorts your data by **games, ascending**:

```
function sort2() {
 range.sort([{column:5,ascending:true}]);
}
```

The function `sort3` sorts your data by **difference, descending**:

```
function sort3() {
 range.sort([{column:10,ascending:false}]);
}
```

Afterwards, in order to assign the above functions, you should create three buttons, like this:
[image]

After creating the buttons, you should assign to each one of the them the above functions:

- **SORT BY POINTS** button -> `sort1`;
- **SORT BY GAMES** button -> `sort2`;
- **SORT BY DIFF** button -> `sort3`;

If you want to use all the sorting criteria in one instruction, you should just use all of them in the same `sort` method.

```
range.sort([{column:11,ascending:false},{column:5,ascending:true},{column:10,ascending:false}]);
```

Furthermore, I suggest you check the above links since they might be of help in your future development:

1. [Sheet Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet);
2. [Range Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Comment: ty for your effort but the thing u described worked already.
What it should do is: Sort by all criteria at the same time, like a real leaderboard would work. So if 2 Players have the same amount of points, the player with less games is in a better place. And if they have the same amount of games the player with the better difference is in a better spot.

Comment: @Robin33 you should put all the sorting in one line then, like this: `range.sort([{column:11,ascending:false},{column:5,ascending:true},{column:10,ascending:false}]);`

Comment: that's what cooper originally responded and it doesnt work

Comment: @Robin33, the ranges are different in this case :)